# What does "fag paper" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

While reading [this](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/jun/11/corbyn-to-postpone-labour-reshuffle-to-take-fight-to-government) article, I was struck when one of the "sources" are quoted as saying

> There is never more than a fag paper between them

I have always understood "fags" to either refer to cigarettes or homosexuals, but what does it mean in this context?

Comment: What makes more sense to you there? A homosexual paper or a cigarette paper?

Comment: @Robusto even if I use the definition which makes more sense to me,  I've never heard of the concept of cigarette paper coming in between people

Comment: from the days when smokers used to roll up their own ciggies, see [image](http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/f907f46d4d634c59ab7330f03c71a4e2/1970s-uk-rizla-magazine-advert-exrg9w.jpg). The cigarette paper is extremely thin, the analogy fits. Corbyn seems like the type of guy who would roll his own cigarettes. I don't know if he is a smoker, he looks like one though.

Comment: The important factor is that cigarette paper is thin. The implication is that they were close/inseperable.

Comment: I'll also note that _fag_ meaning _homosexual_ has never been common in the UK, whereas _fag_ meaning _cigarette_ has.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Smokers still do roll their own. Loose tobacco and Rizla papers are cheaper than manufactured cigarettes. Or so I'm told; I've never seen the attraction of smoking.

Comment: The article is about politicians agreeing/disagreeing on issues.  In context, they're close in their views on particular subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "cigarette paper". It is in *[Cassell's dictionary of slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA485&lpg=PA485&dq=%22fag+paper%22&source=bl&ots=2zmUP1kkC5&sig=XtFfzv5s-8AyKVKlny8_fq1XqSI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz4NetwbbUAhUE_IMKHfBvC10Q6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22fag%20paper%22&f=false)*, 2nd edition by Jonathon Green. The thickness of a cigarette paper is not a very large distance so the quoted sentence means they are always close. It's a metaphor.

Urban Dictionary provides a example of similar usage

"[four foot and a fag paper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=four%20foot%20and%20a%20fag%20paper)" which is supposedly

> Scottish slang to describe someone who is very short.

Comment: Fag papers are approximately one-thousandth of an inch thick, and are widely used by engineers for measuring or setting up very small distances between things. There's a discussion of different makes and grades here: https://www.model-engineer.co.uk/forums/postings.asp?th=166563