# How did 'cigarette paper' shift to signify strife?

Tags: phrase-origin

Source: Rebecca Gowers. [*Plain Words* (2014 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plain-Words-Rebecca-Gowers/dp/0241960347). [p. 208 Middle](https://books.google.com/books?id=6B40AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT224&ots=QalFBJPcwL&dq=%22not%20a%20cigarette%20paper%20between%20myself%22&pg=PT224#v=onepage&q=%22not%20a%20cigarette%20paper%20between%20myself%22&f=false).

> *Note*. Gowers also wrote under this heading: 'About the age- 
>   long conflict between *it is I* and *it is me*, no more need be said 
>   than that, in the present stage of the battle, most people 
>   would think "it is I" pedantic in talk and "it is me" improper 
>   in writing'. Now, however, most people would find 'it is I' 
>   disquietingly fey in any modern context, written or not. By 
>   contrast, the grammatically needless use of *myself* is 
>   flourishing. The Deputy Prime Minister, for one, clearly 
>   believes that *myself* confers a certain something that I and me 
>   both lack: 'Myself and the Prime Minister are saying exactly 
>   the same thing'; **'There is not a cigarette paper between 
>   myself and the Prime Minister on this issue'**, 'But all of us in 
>   this government, including the Prime Minister and myself, 
>   are not willing to compromise ...' etc. ~

Comment: The idiom is the _opposite_ of strife. That there is not enough room between the two to slide the thinnest of papers, signifies how close to unanimity they are.

Comment: Similar: [What does “fag paper” mean in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393495/what-does-fag-paper-mean-in-this-context)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "fag paper" mean in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393495/what-does-fag-paper-mean-in-this-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**paper-thin**  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/paper-thin)

> extremely thin

As in:

> 'There is not a cigarette paper between myself and the Prime Minister
>   on this issue.'

Metaphorically: the differences between the writer and the Prime Minister  are virtually nil ... only the thinnest of paper (in this case a cigarette paper) could come between their positions on X.

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that cigarette paper is particularly thin.